# Good conferences on (computational) neuroscience in Europe and whether to submit to conference or journal?

Tags: publication-process

I'm looking for good (computational) neuroscience conferences in Europe that $\textbf{have proceedings}$. Recommendations? Or are there even such conferences? Should I just send my work to a journal? I'm new in neuroscience, and it seems (compared to CS/Physics) that conferences are not so respected in this field.

Comment: The Bernstein Conference in Germany is nice: http://www.bernstein-conference.de/. Concerning publications: I might be wrong, but I do not think that conference proceedings are that much valued in neuroscience. The standard way is to publish in peer reviewed journals.

Answer (score 3):

To touch on your broader question, as I understand getting full text publications in conferences are highly respected in computer science. In psychology and neuroscience (note I don't know so much about computational neuroscience), publishing papers in high impact journals is more respected in the field. While some conferences do have full-length papers, such publications often carry little weight. It is often tricky to even hunt down such conference proceedings. As such they are often barely part of the published research literature.  So yes, in psychology and neuroscience, you should generally submit your work to journals if you want to maximise its scientific impact.

That said, conferences are important in psychology and the neurosciences. As with any field, conferences are an important opportunity to network, share ideas, form collaborations, learn about developments and so on. A very common strategy is to present a work in progress at a conference. This allows you to set a preliminary deadline, get some feedback, and then refine your ideas before submitting to a journal.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any computational neuroscience conference with proceedings that is always held in Europe.

- Neural information processing systems (NIPS) was held in Europe only once recently, but back in US. (it was in Spain on 2011)
- International joint conference on neural networks (IJCNN) has minor section on computational neuroscience but it's mostly held in the states.
- International conference in acoustics, speech and signal Processing  (ICASSP) sometimes has computational neuroscience related topics, but it's very very minor. It'll be in Italy next year.
- European Symposium on Artificial Neural Networks, Computational Intelligence and Machine Learning (ESANN) seems to have proceedings, but I'm not sure. I have never been to one.

Bernstein Conference and CNS are good conferences but they don't have proceedings, I believe.